# itertools functions not showing up in pydev quick fix

Tags: pydev

Using python 2.7.2 and pydev 2.5.0 and I can't seem to get eclipse to ever suggest any functions from itertools as suggestion.

For example quick fixing the given the following:
chain([1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6])

Only gives logilab.common.compat as an option for quick fixing.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue: PyDev will currently only discover functions it has the source for (and as itertools is a builtin module which PyDev can't analyze, it won't give you auto-import completions for it... note: it does work though if you try to find the module 'itertools' and complete from it).